# How to set JMSExpirationTime on MQ Response message for SOAP/JMS based web service?

Tags: web-services, ibm-mq, websphere-8

We have a SOAP over JMS based web service running on Websphere 8.5.5. The web service receives an MQ request message, processes the request and send back the response. All is well.

Now we have a requirement to set the JMSExpirationTime on the MQ Response message, so that if the calling application does not reads the response in a "specified time" from the queue, then the message should expire, and should not remain on the queue forever.

The Web-service is JAX-RPC based SOAP over JMS. Our SOAP Listsner MDB is an extension of JMSListenerMDB(com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.jms.JMSListenerMDB) which sets the Expiration time by itself IF "the same is set on MQ Request Message else it is set to 0(which is forever)".

How do we set JMSExpirationTime on MQ Response Message, since the message is prepared by IBM API.

Comment: When you say "Websphere 8.5.5" what do you mean, exactly?  WebSphere is a brand, not a product.  When used on its own it usually means WebSphere App Server.  MQ on the other hand left the WebSphere Brand and though it has a v8, it does not have a  v8.5.5.

Answer (score 0):

The `JMSListenerMDB` is responsible for receiving the messages.  There must also be a message producer and destination through which replies are sent.  If the destination is a managed object you can set the Expiry field there.  You can also set it dynamically in the app after the object is instantiated.  Please see the page on [Expiry](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q112090_.htm) in the MQ Knowledge Center.

If the app creates a destination dynamically (for example from the ReplyTo field of the incoming message) then it is customary to set expiry on a per-message basis.  Do this by calling the message producer's `setTimeToLive` method as described in the Knowledge Center docs for [`MQMessageProducer`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQMessageProducer.html).